# For comprehension and Futures is having a type mismatch

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am getting a type mismatch error and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
found:        scala.concurrent.Future[UserSales]
required:     Option[UserSales]

       userSalesOpt <- getOrSetUserSales(userSalesCacheKey)

I have tried creating another for {} clause but that didn't solve the issue.  What should I be doing as I am stuck??
```

Here are the methods I am using:

```
UserDAO
  def getByUsername(name: String): Future[Option[User]]

UserController: 
  def getOrSetUserSales(key: String): Future[Option[UserSales]]

class UserController ... {

  def index = Action.asyc {
    val maybeUserSalesOpt: Future[Option[UserSales]] = for {
      userOpt <- userDao.getByUsername(name)
    } yield {
       for {
          user <- userOpt
          userSalesCacheKey = name + "whatever"
          userSalesOpt <- getOrSetUserSales(userSalesCacheKey)
       } yield {
         for {
           userSales <- userSalesOpt
         } yield userSales
       }
    }

    for {
      maybeUserSales <- maybeUserSalesOpt
    } yield {
      if(maybeUserSales.isDefined) {
        Ok("found")
      } else {
       Ok("error")
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type mismatch comes from the definition of for-comprehension. The resulting type needs to be the same as the stating type.

So if you have a for-comprehension on a List you know that that the resulting type is also a List.

```
for(i <- List(Some(1), None, Some(2)); j <- i ) yield j
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

If I try to return something different, the compiler will complain:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

for(i <- Future.apply(Option(2)); j <- i ) yield j
<console>:**: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
              for(i <- Future.apply(Option(2)); j <- i ) yield j
                                                   ^
```

You are trying to return an Option whereas the return type should be a Future.

---

Here is how to solve this kind of problem in Scala (I abstract everything so it compiles):

```
// Dummy types
type UserSales = String
type User = String

// Types of the main functions we have
type GetByUsername = String => Future[Option[User]]
type GetOrSetUserSales = String => Future[Option[UserSales]]

// Type of the function I want
type UserSaleGetter = (String, String) => Future[Option[UserSales]]

// A function that solves our problem (function combinator) 
def makeConditionalUserSalesGetter(userGetter: GetByUsername, 
                                   salesGetter: GetOrSetUserSales): UserSaleGetter = { 
   (userName: String, prodName: String) => 
      for(optUser <- userGetter(userName); p <- salesGetter(userName+prodName) )
          yield p
}
```

Now we can use the combined function (with type `UserSaleGetter`) to give a user and a product and get back a `Future[Option[UserSales]]`.

Comment: But  my return type is Future[Option[UserSales]] ?

Comment: In the  `for {user <- userOpt ... ` loop you start with an Option (userOpt) and you return a Future (that comes from `getOrSetUserSales()`). That is what the compiler is complaining.